# How do I make Git ignore the contents of a file?

Tags: git

Is there a way to make git ignore the contents of a file?

I have a file that is automatically overwritten by the compiler every time the build process runs, but the compiler fails if the file doesn't exist. Even if the file is completely empty the compiler is still happy. There is no point in updating this file every time I commit in git because its just going to get overwritten anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to just not check in the file at all and do something like `touch /path/to/file` as a precompile step?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=git+ignore

Comment: @Quentin It's not clear, but I think the OP wants the file to exist (empty) in their repo but _not_ be marked as dirty. That's not the same as the usual ignore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tell git never to update a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658449/tell-git-never-to-update-a-file)

Comment: `--assume-unchanged` is kind of a dirty work around since that doesn't communicate back to the remote repository, so every time you check out from origin you need to run `--assume-unchanged` again.

Comment: @vcsjones Unfortunately not really. It is a proprietary IDE that has the compiler hooked right in. I guess I could do something like that as a smudge/clean filter, but that feels a bit ugly.

Comment: @DanPuzey Correct. If the file doesn't exist, it breaks the compiler.

Comment: @vcsjones I read about --assume-unchanged, but it appears that that only effects the local repo. We are using git as part of our deployment tooling (ugly I know), and I need this change in all the clones.

Comment: @ScottWeldon Looks like there is some good advice in there. I might be able to do something like the answer there, but I was hoping to avoid writing more scripts if git could handle it on its own.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in checking such a file in at all. There are two things you need to do here:

1. From Git's side, you need to add this file to `.gitignore`, so git just ignores it completely.
2. From the build's side, you need to make sure the file is there (e.g., on  a *nix system, just `touch` it) before you start the compilation.

Comment: I would love to do that, but it is a proprietary IDE/build system so I don't have any (easy) way to hook the build system to insert the `touch` commands.

Answer (score 2):

No, I am not aware of a way to commit a file and ignore its contents subsequently.  However, why not add the file .gitignore, i.e. leave it untracked by git and cause git to create the file when the repository is cloned and/or checked out.  This can simply be done by placing the following script inside ".git/hooks/post-checkout", remembering to make the file executable (and of course remember to git add the file so it is checked into the repository!).

```
#!/bin/sh

# Create file "myfile" in checkout root.
touch myfile
```

Which would create the file "myfile" if it does not exist already.  And if the file is in the .gitignore it will not be committed and generally be ignored and not clutter up things like running "git status", etc.

I think this elegantly solves your problem.